# jquery.fileupload mudar nome antes do envio

Tags: php, jquery, upload

Tenho um sistema de cadastro de produtos e estou utilizando para envio das imagens o `jquery.fileupload`.

Está funcionando perfeitamente, mas alguns clientes estão tendo problema com o nome do nome duplicado ou nomes com espaço. Alguém ai do grupo pode me ajudar com essa tarefa, como posso estar fazendo isso?

quero agradecer ao Felipe por tentar me ajudar, achei a solução aqui mesmo no grupo mais no site em inglês, para quem estiver com a mesma dúvida está ai a solução https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729204/jquery-blueimp-how-to-change-filename-before-upload, teste e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Você está trabalhando com PHP?

Comment: Sim estou felipe

Comment: Já trabalhei com jquery.upload. Você chega a receber os nomes dos arquivos sem problemas no PHP? Precisamos saber se o ideal é alterar a nomenclatura ANTES de enviar p/ o PHP ou depois, pois com PHP é bem mais fácil.

Comment: olha já não sei como seria mais fácil oque acontece é que após enviar ele grava 3 tamanhos diferente da mesma imagem um thumb, um medio e a imagem real fiz isso pra ficar melhor para trabalhar na minha aplicação. eu acho que seria melhor mudar o nome antes de enviar, oque vc acha? o arquivo php que faz o envio acho ser esse https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Comment: Mas seus clientes estão tendo problemas (não envia) ou precisam que o nome dos arquivos mude? Este é o X da questão, pois se é um problema na hora de enviar (não envia), então deve ser antes (com certeza). Eu prefiro trabalhar com PHP alterando o nome do arquivo e enviando um callback com o novo nome do arquivo para que a lista seja atualizada com o novo nome.

Comment: o envio é feito sim não importa como está o nome, o problema é para exibir que se tiver um nome igual ele coloca (1), (2) e dai estou tendo problema, o arquivo que faz o envio é esse: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Comment: Hmm, me lembro do pesadelo que foi hehe. Escrevi meu próprio `handler` na época, para poder ter menos trabalho de customização. Vou ficar te devendo, mas já adianto que seria: renomear no PHP (handler deles ou seu próprio handler) e retornar usando callback o novo nome do arquivo (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei o problema com esse arquivo:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php